# How to assert that sum of two series is equal to sum of another two series

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have 4 series objects:

```
ser1=pd.Series(data={'a':1,'b':2,'c':NaN, 'd':5, 'e':50})
ser2=pd.Series(data={'a':4,'b':NaN,'c':NaN, 'd':10, 'e':100})
ser3=pd.Series(data={'a':0,'b':NaN,'c':7,'d':15, 'e':NaN})
ser4=pd.Series(data={'a':5,'b':2,'c':10, 'd':NaN, 'e':NaN})
```

I would like to assert
`assert (ser1 + ser2 == ser3 + ser4)` where I treat NaNs as zeros, only not a situation where both ser1 and ser2 are Nans - then I want to ommit this case and treat assert as true. For example when `ser1` and `ser2` are both NaNs ('c') then assert should return True no matter what are the values of `ser3` and `ser4`. In case only one of `ser1` or `ser2` is NaN, filling nans with zeros would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
def assert_sum_equality(ser1, ser2, ser3, ser4):
    """Helper function.
    """
    if ser1.isna().all() and ser2.isna().all():
        return True
    _ = [ser.fillna(0, inplace=True) for ser in [ser1, ser2, ser3, ser4]]
    return all(ser1 + ser2 == ser3 + ser4)
```

```py
import pandas as pd

# ser1 and ser2 are filled with pd.NA
ser1 = pd.Series({"a": pd.NA, "b": pd.NA, "c": pd.NA, "d": pd.NA, "e": pd.NA})
ser2 = pd.Series({"a": pd.NA, "b": pd.NA, "c": pd.NA, "d": pd.NA, "e": pd.NA})
ser3 = pd.Series({"a": 0, "b": pd.NA, "c": 7, "d": 15, "e": pd.NA})
ser4 = pd.Series({"a": 5, "b": 2, "c": 10, "d": pd.NA, "e": 125})

print(assert_sum_equality(ser1, ser2, ser3, ser4))  # True


# ser1 + ser2 == ser3 + ser4 on all rows
ser1 = pd.Series({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 13, "d": 5, "e": 50})
ser2 = pd.Series({"a": 4, "b": pd.NA, "c": 4, "d": 10, "e": 100})
ser3 = pd.Series({"a": 0, "b": pd.NA, "c": 7, "d": 15, "e": pd.NA})
ser4 = pd.Series({"a": 5, "b": 2, "c": 10, "d": pd.NA, "e": 150})

print(assert_sum_equality(ser1, ser2, ser3, ser4))  # True


# ser1 + ser2 != ser3 + ser4 on rows 'c' and 'e'
ser1 = pd.Series({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": pd.NA, "d": 5, "e": 50})
ser2 = pd.Series({"a": 4, "b": pd.NA, "c": pd.NA, "d": 10, "e": 100})
ser3 = pd.Series({"a": 0, "b": pd.NA, "c": 7, "d": 15, "e": pd.NA})
ser4 = pd.Series({"a": 5, "b": 2, "c": 10, "d": pd.NA, "e": pd.NA})

print(assert_sum_equality(ser1, ser2, ser3, ser4))  # False
```